# How would i add gradience to background color in a color clock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

How would i add gradience to the background color? I would like the hours and minutes to control the color and the seconds to control gradience. For a pulsating effect starting from the center, with every second making like a ring of that color that gets darker and darker.

```js
var clock, hour, min, sec, color;

function displayTime(){
clock=new Date();
hour=clock.getHours(),
min=clock.getMinutes(),
sec=clock.getSeconds();

//if single digit, add 0 to the left
if(hour<=9) hour='0'+hour;
if(min<=9) min='0'+min;
if(sec<=9) sec='0'+sec;

color='#'+hour+min+sec;

//set background color
document.body.style.background= color;
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=""+hour+":"+min+":"+sec+"";

//set interval
setInterval(displayTime,1000);
//}
}


displayTime();
```

```css
#time{
 font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10%;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/app-browserify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to make your text look gradienty:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>This Colour</h1>
```

In your case, you can apply the below styles for the `#time`.

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```